# Difficulty understanding thread logic - assigning variables

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

I am reading in two separate text files with two separate threads, and trying to then assign them to to separate HashMaps, and implementing the Runnable interface. The run method calls the file parser method, and assigns it to a class variable - hashMap. How would I go about assigning the separate threads to new HashMap variables? I feel there is a fundamental flaw in my class design.. but any help would be much appreciated.

Edit

```
public void run(){
this.hashMapSubject = getMap(this.text);
    this.hashMapQuery = getMap(this.text); //This just causes an overwrite of data ^^
```

}

```
public class RunnerClass {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Menu m = new Menu();
    m.start(); //gets user input and assigns to user subject, and then userQuery string variables.

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Parser(m.getUserSubject()), "UserSubject");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Parser(m.getUserQuery()), "UserQuery");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();     
    
}
```

Here is my parser class

```
public class Parser implements Runnable {
private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
private String line = "";
private BufferedReader br;
private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMapSubject; //****** Need to assign one to this variable
private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMapQuery; //***** Need to assign one to this variable
private String text;

public Parser(String text) { //new Thread passes user value to constructor parameter
    this.text = text;
}
public Map<Integer, Integer> getMap(String text) {

    this.hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.text)));
                    
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.toLowerCase().replaceAll(",", "");
            String[] words = line.split("(?<=\\G.....)");
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

            for (String word : words) {
                int hash = word.hashCode();
                int frequency = 1;
                if (hashMap.containsKey(hash)) {
                    frequency += hashMap.get(hash);
                }
                hashMap.put(hash, frequency);
                
            }           
        }           
    }
         catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hashMap;
}
@Override //**************************************
public void run() {
    getMap(this.text);

    //********************************************
} //run method here getsMap() for each thread
```

}

An example of the output: I see both threads are executing their tasks but I am stumped on how to extract the data into new variables

```
Enter subject...
Enter Query...
Processing...
UserSubject
UserQuery
UserSubject
UserQuery 
UserSubject //continues like this until termination
```

Comment: In your previous question, now closed, you said that you are relatively new to programming. May I respectfully suggest that you are too new to be messing with threads?. Threads can be a way to make a complex program look simple while simultaneously introducing deep and subtle bugs that can challenge even an experienced programmer to find and fix. I think you should start with something simpler. Have you got a working, _single_ threaded version of the program?

Comment: Hi Solomon, true - I may well be too inexperienced to be messing around with threads. The single threaded version works without issues and doesn't challenge my understanding. This is a coding exercise I have been assigned, so am trying my best to find a workaround. It looks like I will just have to figure it out one way or another but that's all part of the process! Thank you for your feedback though

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You say things like, "...assigning the separate threads to new HashMap variables," but that doesn't make any sense: A `Thread` is not a thing that you can assign to a `HashMap` variable. The compiler won't allow you to do it because `Thread` and `HashMap` are different types. It's not clear why you would _want_ to do that because "thread" and "hash map" are completely different ideas. It feels as if, either you have not spent much time thinking about what you want your program to do, or else you haven't spent much time learning what Java programs _can_ do.

Comment: That's a fair enough comment. I'll take care to better review and understand what I'm asking before posting. I've been stuck on this for days so I possibly have spent too much time mulling over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Solomon Slow said in the comment, writing multi threaded code is hard. With that said, here are my comments and suggestions.

First a few observations:

- The text is passed to the constructor and stored in a field. It is then passed from run() to getMap(). This is unnecessary since getMap() can also see the class field text.
- getMap() returns the map but the the return value is ignored in run().
- The BufferedReader br could be a local variable in getMap().
- The String line could be a local variable in getMap().
- The String text could be final
- The HashMap could be final and instantiated in the constructor
- In the while loop, the result of replaceAll() is ignored (Strings are immutable, you'll need to use the return value.)

These things don't address your question but will make the class a little bit cleaner and less mutable. (Some of this might be subjective.)

Looking only at the Parser there is no way of knowing it's state (new, running, finished, etc.). While it might not be very important for your use case, I generally like to keep track of state in multi threaded applications. Some boolean flags can solve this, or an enum if you want. This can be used to prevent accidentally trying to run getMap() twice for example.

If this is meant to only ever be run as a Thread (with run() ) I would make getMap() private. I might also consider renaming it to parseFile() to free the name getMap() for a getter method for the map to be called once the parsing is complete.

Modified code:

```
public class Parser implements Runnable {
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
    private final String text;

    private enum ParserState {NEW, RUNNING, DONE}

    private ParserState state;

    public Parser(String text) { //new Thread passes user value to constructor parameter
        this.text = text;
        this.hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.state = ParserState.NEW;
    }

    private void processFile() {
        if (state != ParserState.NEW) {
            return;
        }

        this.state = ParserState.RUNNING;
        String line = "";

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.text)));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.toLowerCase().replaceAll(",", ""); // Don't forget to use the replaceAll() return value
                String[] words = line.split("(?<=\\G.....)");

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

                for (String word : words) {
                    int hash = word.hashCode();
                    int frequency = 1;
                    if (hashMap.containsKey(hash)) {
                        frequency += hashMap.get(hash);
                    }
                    hashMap.put(hash, frequency);

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.state = ParserState.DONE;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return state == ParserState.DONE;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getMap() {
        if (state != ParserState.DONE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }

    @Override //**************************************
    public void run() {
        processFile();
    }

    //********************************************
} //run method here getsMap() for each thread
```

And the runner:

```
public class RunnerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.start(); //gets user input and assigns to user subject, and then userQuery string variables.

        Parser userSubjectParser = new Parser(m.getUserSubject());
        Parser userQueryParser = new Parser(m.getUserQuery());

        Thread t1 = new Thread(userSubjectParser, "UserSubject");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(userQueryParser, "UserQuery");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        // Wait until both threads are finished

        Map<Integer, Integer> hashMapSubject = userSubjectParser.getMap();
        Map<Integer, Integer> hashMapQuery = userQueryParser.getMap();

    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to make a similar list, but you beat me to it. Here's one item that was in my list, but not in yours: ...using `word.hashCode()` as a key to a hash map instead of just using `word` as the key.

Comment: Thank you  I really appreciate that. It has really clarified a lot of the flawed logic I was using, and your observations clarified where I was going wrong.  Thanks to both of you DarkMatter and Solomon for helping a newbie out!!

Comment: @SolomonSlow Good catch! I totally missed that.

Comment: Just to confirm the code is running smoothly now after those suggested modifications. Genuinely has made my day. I definitely need to go over some of the fundamentals again and become more proficient before tackling these problems. Thanks again